# Setting up additional breadcrumb re-direct using mod_rewrite

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, mod-rewrite, http, redirect

Currently I have mod_rewrite configured as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName  address.website.org
ServerAdmin webmaster@website.org

DocumentRoot /var/www

Redirect permanent / http://www.website.org/site

ErrorLog  /var/log/apache2/connect.website.org-error.log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/connect.website.org-access.log combined
```

I need to include a redirect for the following:

http://address.website.org/site/site > http://www.website.org/site/site

I have edited the web addresses for privacy. As you can see, I basically just need to add a breadcrumb somehow, while maintaining the original redirect.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName  address.website.org
ServerAdmin webmaster@website.org

DocumentRoot /var/www

Redirect permanent /site http://www.website.org/site/site
Redirect permanent / http://www.website.org/site

ErrorLog  /var/log/apache2/connect.website.org-error.log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/connect.website.org-access.log combined
```